# Send notification to other browsers with Blazor

Tags: signalr, blazor-server-side, signalr-hub

I am writing a blazor server application.

I have a textbox+button in a page and a grid. What i want to do is to allow users to type some text in the texbox. The text should be added to the grid.

What i want is to automatically refresh grid on all browsers when a new message is typed.

I have tried and manage to do that with signalr and signalr hub. It works like a charm.

But i am wondering something: Blazor server creates a signalr connexion between server and browser. My signalr hub is creating a second signalr connexion.

Is there a way to do that without creating a second signalr connexion.
In other words, is there a way to send notifications to browsers without a signalr hub ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my view of your problem is correct.

I suspect you're trying to create a *direct* Signalr connection point-to-point between clients, without any centralized hub.
Right?

If this is the case I think it's impossible using only Signalr, because the server maintains a list of clients ip/port connected to the hub and this list isn't shared between clients.

I don't know if there is any kind of project based on Signalr that enable a Blazor WASM application to *expose* itself as a server in order to receive communication **directly** from other WASM Client, but in the world of gaming all is possible !

Comment: No, i do not want to create direct signalr connections p2p between clients, i want to use the same websocket for my hub and for blazor